# Caused by: org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'java.lang.CharSequence': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18

Tags: java, exception, aspectj

I am trying to upgrade my web application from JDK 1.7 to JDK 1.8.

I have changed the compiler and targeted JDK to 1.8 for my application and in testing environment the JDK property has been updated to jdk 1.8 in was server.

But I am getting the below error:
WARN [server.startup : 0] o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext [AbstractApplicationContext.java:487] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

With some more bean initialization failed and cause by as below:-

Caused by: org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'java.lang.CharSequence': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18

Solutions tried:-

Aspectjrt and aspectweaver jars are already been updated to 1.8.13 and also tried using 1.9.6 for the same
but this did not resolve the issue.

The plugin used is as below:-

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                 <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.13</version>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.13</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
             </plugin>
```

Can anyone please provide some suggestion to fix this issue??
Adding the  spring dependencies

```
<properties>
        <springframework-version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springframework-version>
        </properties>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!! Are you using Spring Framework as part of your dependency? Could you show your Dependency list from `pom.xml`.

Comment: Hi Thanks, yes using spring framework ,added the dependencies from pom.xml.

Comment: Hey, What version of Spring Framework you are using? I particularly wanted to see the Spring Framework's dependency pom. Sorry if I was not clear in the above comment. Can you show your Spring Dependencies? I suspect the Spring version you have is using an older version of `aspectJ` as it's dependency. I may be wrong.. just trying to figure out.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response, using spring 4                                                                            <springframework-version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springframework-version>
Which jars really matters for aspectJ issues other than spring aop and spring aspect ??

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you use AspectJ Maven plugin, it means you wish to use native AspectJ. You do not need any Spring for that. Or are you using native AspectJ instead of Spring AOP for some reason from within a Spring application? Your POM alone does not answer that question. I need to see application code, aspect(s) and, if applicable, Spring configuration. This is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please provide one, so I someone help you better thany wildly speculating. Thank you so much.

Comment: @kriegaex I think you are right. I'm not able to figure out the problem here. More inputs may help.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the response.
Actually I managed it to resolve by deleting the older jars of aspectj(1.6 version) in testing server.
Somehow, the server was having the old jars which were not getting cleared up with each deployment.
So after deleting those jars, application got up.